# The type or namespace name 'Confidence' does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, .net, soap, bing-maps

I'm using `Bing Maps`, `SOAP`, `c#`, and `.net`. I want to implement `GeocodeAddress()`, but  the type or namespace name `'Confidence'` does not exist in the namespace :

```
private String GeocodeAddress(string address)
        {
            string results = "";
            string key = "insert your Bing Maps key here";
            GeocodeRequest geocodeRequest = new GeocodeRequest();

            // Set the credentials using a valid Bing Maps key
            geocodeRequest.Credentials = new                DevExpress.Map.BingServices.Credentials();
            geocodeRequest.Credentials.ApplicationId = key;

            // Set the full address query
            geocodeRequest.Query = address;

            // Set the options to only return high confidence results 
            ConfidenceFilter[] filters = new ConfidenceFilter[1];
            filters[0] = new ConfidenceFilter();

            filters[0].MinimumConfidence = GeocodeService.Confidence.High;

            // Add the filters to the options
            GeocodeOptions geocodeOptions = new GeocodeOptions();
            geocodeOptions.Filters = filters;
            geocodeRequest.Options = geocodeOptions;

            // Make the geocode request
            GeocodeServiceClient geocodeService = new     GeocodeServiceClient();
            GeocodeResponse geocodeResponse =         geocodeService.Geocode(geocodeRequest);

            if (geocodeResponse.Results.Length > 0)
                results = String.Format("Latitude: {0}\nLongitude: {1}",
                  geocodeResponse.Results[0].Locations[0].Latitude,
                  geocodeResponse.Results[0].Locations[0].Longitude);
            else
                results = "No Results Found";

            return results;
        }
```

Comment: Code looks identical (at first glance) to the code [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd221354.aspx). Have you changed anything?

Comment: i only change this:
   geocodeRequest.Credentials = new              DevExpress.Map.BingServices.Credentials(); @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: And when you added the service reference, did you make sure the name you gave to the service was `GeocodeService`? I.e. the first part of that name is whatever name you gave to the service reference, and it's easy to accidentally just accept `ServiceReference1` as the name of the reference.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the very old SOAP services for Bing Maps. The Bing Maps team stopped recommending using those over 6 years ago. The Bing Maps REST services are much faster, have more features and are regularly updated. Documentation on the REST services can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx

There is documentation on how to use the REST services in .NET here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819168.aspx

I also recommend checking out the best practices document here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn894107.aspx